# How to migrate from github to bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have migrated my repository from Github to Bitbucket. How do I point my local branch from github to bitbucket?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/ (and obviously using the bitbucket repository urls)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

> git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]

so just do e. g. `git remote set-url origin <bitbucket url>`

Answer (score 0):

if you have existing git setup then go to .git folder and find gitconfig file and replace the github url inside that with bitbucket url.